# Div changes size once another div is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So, i am having an issue with a div, when another div is generated (via javascript) below it, it is changing the size of the div.

```js
// for the side nav message list

const chatList = function(list) {
    let br = document.createElement("br")

    for (let index in list) {
        try {

        let chat = list[index]

        let chatBodyParent = document.createElement("div")
        chatBodyParent.onclick = function() {
            $("#message-list").empty()
            api.listMessages(chat.chat.id)
            document.getElementById("message-list").channelId = chat.chat.id
        }
        chatBodyParent.id = `chat-body-${chat.chat.id}`

        let chatBody = document.createElement("div")
        chatBody.className = "chat-body"

        let chatImg = document.createElement("img")
        chatImg.src = chat.chat.cover
        if (!chat.chat.cover && chat.chat.type == 1) {
            chatImg.src = "/dump/pfp.svg"
        }
        if (!chat.chat.cover && chat.chat.type == 3) {
            chatImg.src = "/dump/public.png"
        }
        chatImg.className = "chat-img"
        chatImg.setAttribute("align", "left")
        chatBody.appendChild(chatImg)


        let chatInfoContainer = document.createElement("div")
        chatInfoContainer.className = "chat-info-container"

        let chatName = document.createElement("span")
        chatName.className = "chat-name"
        chatName.innerText = chat.chat.title

        chatInfoContainer.appendChild(chatName)
        chatInfoContainer.appendChild(br.cloneNode(true))
        
        let chatMessageContent = document.createElement("span")
        chatMessageContent.className = "chat-message-content"
        chatMessageContent.id = `chat-message-content-${chat.chat.id}`
        let messageContent
        if (chat.message) {
            let long = false;

            if (chat.message.text.length >= 30) {
                long = true
            }

            messageContent = chat.message.text.substring(0, 30)
            if (long) {
                messageContent += "..."
            }
            
        } else if (chat.type == "file") {
            messageContent = chat.user.nick + " sent a file"
        }
        
        chatMessageContent.innerText = messageContent

        chatInfoContainer.appendChild(chatMessageContent)
        chatBody.appendChild(chatInfoContainer)

        chatBodyParent.appendChild(chatBody)

        document.getElementById("chat-list").appendChild(chatBodyParent)
        } catch {
            console.log(list[index])
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 15%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: var(--lightish-grey);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  
  .sidenav a {
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
  }
  
  .main {
    margin-left: 15%; 
    padding: 0px 10px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
  }


::-webkit-scrollbar {
  color: var(--grey);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  color: var(--grey);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  color: var(--grey);
}

.menu {
  width: 90%;
  min-width: 90%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  background-color: var(--menu-grey);
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: "FontRegular";
}

.chat-bar {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 1%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 3.5%;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: hidden;
    border-left: hidden;
    border-right: hidden;
    border-bottom: solid var(--light-grey);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: var(--grey);
    color: var(--light-grey);
    font-family: "FontRegular";
}

.chat-bar:focus {
    outline-width: 0;
}

.chat-body {
  width: 90%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  border: 3px;
  border-top: hidden;
  border-left: hidden;
  border-right: hidden;
  /*border-bottom: solid var(--light-grey);*/
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: "FontRegular";
}

.chat-body:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.chat-body:focus {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.chat-img {
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.chat-info-container {
  position:relative; 
  top: 10%; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>iFChat - Dashboard</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/dashboard.css"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/utils.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/api.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dashboard.js"></script>
    </head>
        <div class="sidenav">
            <div id="menu" class="menu">
            </div>
            <div>
            </div> <br><br>
            <div id="chat-list">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main" id="main">
                <div id="message-list" class="message-list"> 
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="chat..." id="chat-bar" class="chat-bar" placeholder="chat..." maxlength="500">
        </div>
</html>
```

Here is an image before the chat list is loaded
Then menu is loaded with the correct size and margin
[pre-load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7dg2.png)

after the chat list loads, it changes the width or margin of the div above some how, and im not sure how or why its doing that, but i cant figure it out, heres an image of after the chat list is loaded [post-load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDVia.png)

i have tried different margins and positioning settings but cant seem to get it to work, any help is greatly appreciated :)

edit: One possible solution may be to change the css with javascript every time the chat list is loaded, but i would like to avoid that if at all possible.

Comment: As a side note, if anyone wants to help with another part of this question thats unrelated, i am trying to position the menu to always be there, even when the message list is scrolled down on. Right now it scrolls with overflow.

Comment: Your code does not output the issue, please attach the final generated code so we can actually see the issue

Comment: The output is exactly whats listed in the css, there is no difference in the css when the div is changed, which is why i can't figure this out on my own, bc if there was a way to find the error and work backwards i would do it, this is my last resort.

Comment: The output of the html is what people needs so they can see what's going on. Most of the time you need css and html to see something that has a problem. It is best to create a simplified example of what the problem is that way people can play with it and solve it fairly fast

Answer (score 0):

OK, so i figured out the issue, the issue occurs when enough elements pop up to trigger the scrollbar, so the fix for me was this

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Because i want a user to beable to scroll, but i dont want there to be a scrollbar, My next plan is to make this static, so that it doesnt move on scroll at all. Still the issue was arising when my (invisible scroll bar, that still had a width) was appearing. Gotta watch out for hidden elements.